# Joining Multiple tables(Entities) with hibernate criteria

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to join multiple enties/tables in hibernate, I have been finding this difficult as am trying to not use HQL.

Here is my query

```
select * from tax_payer_certificate,tcc_issuance where tax_payer_certificate.certficate_fk = tcc_issuance.certficate_fk and tcc_issuance.year_fk = 95657 
and tcc_issuance.issue_date >= '2017-07-26' and 
tcc_issuance.issue_date <= '2017-08-28' and 
tcc_issuance.portal_user_fk != 101460
```

Where the tables are separate entities.

```
public class TaxPayerCertificate implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2818762098412687298L;
    private Timestamp dateCreated;
    private Boolean isConfirmed = false;
    private Timestamp dateConfirmed;
    private Long id;
    private TaxOffice originatingTaxOffice;
    private PortalUser confirmedBy;
    private Year year;
    private TaxPayer taxPayer;

}
```

certificate entity

```
public class Certficate implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7947523303129657154L;
    private String certificateNumber;
    private Date issueDate;
    private Date expiryDate;
    private CertificateTypeConstant type;
    private Long id;
}
```

TccIssuance entity

```
 public class TccIssuance implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID;
        private Timestamp dateGenerated;
        private String certificateNumber;
        private Date issueDate;
        private Date expiryDate;
        private Long id;
        private Year year;
        private PortalUser portalUser;
        private TaxOffice originatingTaxOffice;
        private Certficate certficate;
    }
```

This is an entity class that have been generated from a UML

Comment: you have to use relationship in entity and after that u can join.

Comment: You should probably provide the relevant part of your entity classes here. It's been a hot minute since I used Hibernate, but you shouldn't really need a "join" operation here; or really at all often anywhere else either. `TaxPayerCertificate.issuance` should be a navigation property in your Java model classes, and current versions of Hibernate should be able to generate a JPA 2.0 metamodel for typesafe Criteria queries to handle the filtering.

Comment: @useless'MJ, how do you mean.

Comment: @millimoose, I have provided this.

Comment: Why don't you have any association properties? You have `TccIssuance.certificate`, you should probably have something like its inverse `Certificate.tccIssuances` of type `Collection<TccIssuance>`. Same for `TaxPayerCertificate` and `Certificate` - your query shows the former has a `certificate_fk`, but your entity class doesn't have a property with the type `Certificate`, neither do `Certificate`s have a reference to `TccIssuance`.

Comment: Remember that using Hibernate, you're doing queries over your entity model, not over database tables. You can't meaningfully query using attributes you don't have mapped in your model.